# Значение сочетания „стоять под“?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

В книге „Явление и смысл“ Г. Г. Шпет (в длинной сноске на с. 99–100 изд. 1996 г.) цитирует книгу Б. В. Яковенко „Философия Гуссерля“, и в этой цитате упомянутое в заголовке сочетание употребляется дважды:

> Феноменология Гуссерля **стоит под** целым рядом определенных категорий психического бытия … (c. 99)

> феноменология не „**стоит под**“ категорией „психического бытия“, так как последнее есть эмпирическое бытие, а феноменология говорит о *чистом сознании* … (c. 100)

В словарях и в Интернете я ничего подходящего не нашел.  Единственное, что приходит в голову — подчинение видового понятия родовому — явно не подойдет.  Так в чем же значение этого сочетания здесь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, тут примерно тот же смысл, что в выражении *"находиться под юрисдикцией"*.

То есть если "феноменология Гуссерля стоит под целым рядом определенных категорий психического бытия", то на неё *распространяется влияние* этого *целого ряда категорий*, причём влияние одностороннее — сверху вниз.